# Why do these two series expansions multiplied to be $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\left( \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac1{p!}\right)\left(\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \right) =1$$

Why do these two series expansion multiplied to be $1$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$$

Answer (score 4):

Siong Thye Goh's response is certainly the best way to go about this, but it may be interesting to see we can show this directly:
$$\begin{align}\left( \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac1{p!}\right)\left(\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \right) &= \sum_{p=0}^\infty \sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac1{p!} \cdot \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{q=0}^r \frac1{(r-q)!} \cdot \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r!} \sum_{q=0}^r \binom{r}{q}(-1)^q\end{align}$$
But now observe that if $r \neq 0$, 
$$0=(1+(-1))^r = \sum_{q=0}^r \binom{r}{q}(-1)^q$$
and if $r = 0$, then the sum on the right is $1$. So, the only term left in the double sum is the $r=0$ contribution, and is exactly $1$, as required.